# How does the climax make sense?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, dont-breathe

In the movie *Don't Breathe*, the very first opening scene shows the old man dragging Rocky in the street, and a thick trail of blood left behind. But at the end of the movie, Rocky was about to leave with her daughter and was at the station. From the beginning scene, it seems that Rocky was fatally hurt, so how was it possible for her to leave with her daughter, so soon after the incident without taking medical assistance?

I am saying "soon", because she was looking at the television where the news of the invasion was showing, which was of course on the very next day of the incident or on the same day maybe. What is the most probable explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, **spoiler-alert**!

Yes, the movie begins with a slowly zooming shot of the blind antagonist  dragging an unconscious Rocky back towards his house, however, **there is no trail of blood, just cracks in the dilapidated road and she does not appear to be as injured as you believe.**

I would provide you with relevant screenshots if I could, but the movie is not yet available for private ownership.

This moment in the movie must have happened after he knocks her unconscious when she exits the car where she has trapped his dog. **There is no reason to believe that she is bleeding profusely.**

Answer (score -2):

Movies do not represent realistic injury healing time.

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HollywoodHealing